# Web API POST object with relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, webapi

I have to built a small C# Web API where one can GET/POST/PUT some objects. These objects have relationships with other objects. (Foreign keys in database).

My problem is I am not sure how to post object A, that relates to Object B,C & D also.
I am using EF.

Is the best option to use DTO's for this matter?
Any guidance in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't quite the right place for architecture and design questions. You might have better luck at http://codereview.stackexchange.com or http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. Either way, how does `A` relate to `B`, `C`, and `D`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using Repository Pattern? If so, you can partner that with DTO or ViewModel.

In my understanding of your problem, you just wanted to make changes to multiple tables at the same time. Then you're right, you can use DTO and ViewModel approach here.